# Euler Implicit method with arrays

Tags: python

I've been trying to code an implicit euler method for a school project.
It's about a pendulum acted on by gravity with friction.
The equation is therefore split in 2

```
def pend(y, t, b, c):
    theta, omega = y
    dydt = [omega, -b*omega - c*np.sin(theta)]
    return dydt
```

`b`, `c` are constants.
Here is the euler method

```
def Euler(f,tinit,tfinal, THinit,N,b,c):
    h= (tfinal-tinit)/N #step
    TH = [THinit] #initialization TH = [theta,omega]
    lt = [tinit]
    t=tinit
    y=THinit
    while t<tfinal:
        t= t+h
        lt.append(t) #list of time
        result =scipy.optimize.fsolve(lambda x:x-y-h*f(x,t,b,c), y) 
        TH.append(r)
        y=result
    return TH,lt
```

Using this code for `f = pend`, I get the error

> TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'float'

Maybe we can't use `fsolve` for functions having arrays parameters and/or returning arrays. Thanks for your help.

Full-code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import scipy.optimize
g=9.81
L=0.5
def pend(y, t, b, c):
    theta, omega = y
    dydt = [omega, -b*omega - c*np.sin(theta)]
    return dydt


def Euler(f,tinit,tfinal, THinit,N,b,c):
    h= (tfinal-tinit)/N
    TH = [THinit]
    lt = [tinit]
    t=tinit
    y=THinit
    while t<tfinal:
        t= t+h
        lt.append(t)
        result =scipy.optimize.fsolve(lambda x:x-y-h*f(x,t,b,c), y)
        TH.append(r)
        y=result
    return TH,lt
Y,X = Euler(pend,0,10,[np.pi/8,0],100,0.25,5)
plt.plot(X,Y)
plt.show()
```

Comment: sorry to say, but your variable names are very 'unspeaking' - please add the exact stacktrace - `f=pend` only assigns your function a second name and does not call it. It is best to show a [mcve] that we can copy and that replicates the exact error.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow!  Here you can ① post your code (as a [mcve]), ② describe what you observe it does (with which input), and ③ describe what you expect to observe instead.  This results in a clear question which can be answered.  Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read the [How-To-Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to learn more about this.

Comment: I think you're getting the error here `h*f(x,t,b,c)` when f=pend, right? Do you intend f to return a list or a vector? For example, are you trying to multiply the vector f(..) by a scalar h?

Comment: I edited my post with the full code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the error you're seeing:

```
In [1]: 3.2 * [1,2,3]
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-5-73b36d584f00> in <module>()
----> 1 3.2 * [1,2,3]

TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'float'
```

The reason for this is the semantics for the `*` operator on lists.

```
In [2]: 3 * [1,2,3]
Out[2]: [1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3]
```

You probably mean to multiply a vector by a scalar

```
In [3]: 3 * numpy.array([1,2,3])
Out[3]: array([3, 6, 9])

In [4]: 3.2 * numpy.array([1,2,3])
Out[4]: array([ 3.2,  6.4,  9.6])
```

Therefore pend should return `numpy.array(dydt)`

Comment: Thanks for the fast anwer, the code works great now !

Answer (score 0):

Your `pend()` returns a list (`return [omega, -b*omega - c*np.sin(theta)]` via variable `dydt`).  This list is then used in the term `h*f(x,t,b,c)`.  `h` is a `float`, so you try to multiply a `float` and a `list`.  This isn't possible.  Multiplying an `int` with a `list` is possible and results in a repetition of the list:

```
5 * [ 42, 23 ]
```

results in

```
[ 42, 23, 42, 23, 42, 23, 42, 23, 42, 23 ]
```

But for floats this isn't defined.  Please provide more information about what you expect to happen.  Given only (this kind of) code it is a hard thing to guess.

EDIT:

From what was added later I now guess you want to multiply each element of the array by the float and expect an array as a result.  This is what `numpy` arrays are doing, so I propose to return a `numpy` array right away:

```
dydt = np.array([omega, -b*omega - c*np.sin(theta)])
return dydt
```

Comment: That was such a newbie error (i've been trying to figure this out all day). It works great now, thanks for the fast answer!

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow!  No need to give thank-you messages as comments (in fact that's even a bit frowned upon as spam).  If an answer was helpful, you are encouraged to upvote it instead.